# cannot load such file -- motion/project/ with rubymotion

Tags: rubymotion

hello I got a project rubymotion, when I do rake he said
can not load such file - motion/project/ so I verified my rakefile
I have:

```
$:. unshift ("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/'
```

and /Library/RubyMotion/lib

I have my repertoire motion in I'm project.

So I do not see what is missing.

my ruby version is: 1.9.3-P448

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using this:

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
```